# MySQLdb Results

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to be able to get all the information from MySQLdb using the SELECT * FROM query. I have the following code:

```
            database = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "pswd", "Kazzah")
            cursor = database.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Email=%s AND Password=%s", (_Email, _Password)) 
            database.commit()
            numrows = cursor.rowcount
            results = cursor.fetchall()

            print numrows

            for result in results:
                print result
```

How can I make variables that hold each piece of info from result. If it result returns:

```
(28L, 'Name', 'Last', 'email@email.com', 'pswd', '10000')
```

I want to make a variable called ID and get the first part of the result which is 28L, and so forth with each other pieces of information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

To set the full set of data use this :

```
id, fname, lname, email, pswd, whatever = result
```

And for particular values, try [indexing](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: What I am looking for is to set each variable like fname equal to the second piece in result. Not set the whole result, just a piece of it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just blanked out for a second. Feel stupid asking this question now, haha.